# Google Document translation

Tags: node.js, google-translate

Like Text translation in google API service , I need to translate documents as well. Is there a way by which I could translate docs on my site using google translation.

Just like the web interface of google doc translation. I need to use the same feature through an API in my App.

Documents Are stored on my server and I need to translate and store the translated version of those documents on my server.

I am using **nodeJs** as a server side language.

Comment: Why can't you read the doc, save it as a stream, then send strings to the Translate API? That is the only way to do what you want. In general though, your question here is WAY too broad for Stack, bounty or not.

Comment: Will I able to write the string back to the file with the format preserved. ?

Comment: Unless you save the formatting before sending the string, no. This will give you translated content without formatting. There is no way to send a doc to the translate API and ask it to keep formatting

Comment: It's of no use then as I don't want to display translated text only rather I need translated doc. Anyways thanks for response.

Comment: There is no tool that I know of that can provide something like that. In any case, how would formatting be kept if you translate from English to Chinese, where the sentences are built differently? If formatting includes some bolding, what do you bold in the translation? This is not really something feasible to do.

Comment: By Formatting I simply mean that the translated resource should look somewhat similar to the original doc else It would not make sense.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't see a way to do this (add right-to-left languages to the mix and it gets a WHOLE other layer of complicated)... and "somewhat similar" is not a clear requirement for a tool like this.... In any case, this is a very off-topic question for Stack, since you should not be asking for tools here.

Comment: May be u are right where can I post then. ? As Stack is always on top of list for such things.

Comment: Depends. To GET a tool that would do that, I would suggest Google Groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-translate-api). That might only get you Google tools, but people MAYBE know how to fulfill your needs there. Or you can go on the public issue tracker to make a request to get this tool created, if you want it google-made. There is NO guarantee it will be made (or when, if it is), but that would be where you would make Feature Requests for the tools (here is the Tracker https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list)

Comment: Ok Thanks for response.

Comment: You can try to use Apps Script which exposes a [Translate service object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/language-app) when in the script of a doc. You can also [install/create a translate add-on which translates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

I basically opened the document in a new window and then injected Google Website Translator plugin on this new document window. This enabled me to view the translated version of my entire document.

https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534601?hl=en

Comment: I'm trying to implement the same solution, can you post some code please (document dowload, window creation and plugin injection) ?

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible for you to use Google's website translator code that you can embed into your website to accomplish translations?

http://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en